# "SQLiteException: unable to open database file" - Android app on Blackberry 10

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

We've ported our android application on Blackberry 10. It works fine, but some users get "The application has stopped unexpectedly" error on launch. Stack trace of the error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1849)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:544)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
```

On Android devices and Blackberry emulator we've never faced the error, so I guess it's something wrong with devices or BB runtime for android apps. Has somebody faced the same issue? And is there any workaround?

Comment: Where is the database? In the app or on SD card? Check paths

Comment: Database is created in android code, so I guess it's in internal memory. I don't have a device, where the error occurs, so I can't say exactly.